# Product of Cycles: Name to denote "direction" of composition

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, terminology, symmetric-groups, convention

Is there a notation to denote the difference between these two products of cycles? It seems as though there are two conventions out there that should have a specific name for them. The subscripts for α: r uses the right to left convention and l uses the left to right convention. Not sure what else to call it.

α=(1,3,2)(4,2)

$α_r$=(1,3,2,4)

$α_l$=(1,3,4,2)

Comment: I get $\alpha_l=(1,3,4,2).$ How do you get $(1,2,3)(4,2)$?

Comment: @bof Um, I get $(1324)$.

Comment: @MattSamuel I get $(1,3,2,4)$ when I multiply from right to left, but I get $(1,3,4,2)$ when I multiply from left to right.

Comment: @bof oh, I guess I agree then. I don't understand why anyone would do it that way. When you do right to left you have the wonderful identity $(abcde)=(abc)(cde)$, which seems much more natural than $(abcde)=(cde)(abc)=(dec)(cab)$.

Comment: @MattSamual It's the "action on the right" vs "action on the left" thing; that way $f \circ g$ means that $f$ happens first, etc. Kind of quirky, but not unheard of (my algebra professors were students of Isaacs, who's a big proponent of "action on the right". So I've grown up with the cognitive dissonance of doing things both ways).

Comment: That makes sense to me (just want to be technical). I think I'll notate the direction I am multiplying to make it more explicit for now on. Glad I'm not the only one who thinks of it as "quirky." For the record, I agree that the left to right multiplication (as far as I've seen) is much less common than the right to left multiplication for multiplication of these cycles.